# Set a PrintStream object to a filewriter

Tags: java

I have these two methods in a class:

```
 public SimpleTreeWriterImpl(PrintStream out) {
    outStream = out;
}

@Override
public void setDestination(PrintStream output) {
    outStream = output;

}
```

but now I need to set outStream to print to a text file, however I am not sure how to do this, I tried passing a `File` object to the `setDestination()` method but it says that these are incompatible types.

How can I set the destination to a specific text file?

Comment: Just to confirm when you say "I tried parsing a file" - do you mean that you tried ***passing*** a `File` object into the `setDestination()` method?

Comment: yes, I did mean that

Comment: OK - edited your question - you can also add corrections etc [using the edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28832155/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PrintStream writetoEngineer = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Engineer.txt", true));
```

Comment: but i need to set the destination to a specific file

Comment: I think this answer could use a little context - I think @joaomarcos is suggesting that you set up a `PrintStream` object based on a `FileOutputStream` object which can relate to any file you like (in his example `"Engineer.txt"`).  You can then pass this object (in his example `writetoEngineer`) into your existing `setDesination()` method and it should all just work.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `File` is not a `PrintStream`.  Your `setDestination()` method will only take objects of type `PrintStream`.  So, you need to instantiate a `PrintStream` object (or a subclass of `PrintStream`)

Looking at the [`PrintStream` api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), we see that you can [construct a `Prinstream` directly from a `String` filename](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream%28java.lang.String%29).  This is true for (at least) Java versions 6,7 and 8.  So, what you need is to call the method setDestination as follows:

```
setDestination(new PrintStream("path/to/your/output/file.txt"));
```

**Note** - Prinstream also has a [constructor that takes a `File` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream%28java.io.File%29), so if you are dealing with the `File` object instead of the `String` filename - use the following:

```
setDestination(new PrintStream(yourFileObject));
```